# Merge two git repository by applying one ontop of another

Tags: git, merge

I have two git repositories, one "upstream", that somewhat contains the code from upstream author ( was reacted by an ad-hoc script parsing his in-house rev store ), and the other is the repository I've been working in, which is based on one revision on the upstream repository, but uncertain which.

I've tried going an `git rebase`, but it introduces way many conflicts, so I decided it wasn't wort trying to merge my changed directly, but instead just applying them ontop, i.e.:

```
upstream: A → B → C → D → E → F
mine:             ↳   G → H → I
```

to become

```
A → B → C → D → E → F → G → H → I
```

Now I actually wonder how to accomplish this... can't really just use `cat` :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest `git merge -s ours`, but I'm a little worried by the fact that a rebase generated a lot of conflicts -- this tells me that if you do this you are likely to nuke out upstream changes you may wish to keep.  You should probably take a close look at what's conflicting, possibly by doing a `git cherry-pick` on your commits one at a time.